# Data not displaying in JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, api

I am making a Pokedex API as a side project and I can not display the data needed to display in the different text boxes. I am using a GET request to request the height, weight, type, and ability.

```
<script>

$("button").click( function(){

    var pokemonName = $('pokemon').val(pokemon);
    event.preventDefault();
    getPokemonData(pokemonName);
})

function getPokemonData(pokemonName){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

//GET request with link

 request.open('GET','https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokemonName, true);
// request for data
 request.onload =function(){
     var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
     if(request.status >= 200 && request.status <= 400)
     {
       // outputs data
       $(pokemonheight).val(response.height)
       $(pokemonweight).val(response.weight)
       $(pokemonAblity).val(response.ability)
       $(pokemonType).val(response.type)
     }
     else
     {
       alert ("Error");
     }
     request.send();
                          }
                                  }
</script>
</html>
```

I have tried setting a variable that would be equal to the response JSON element and then input that into the value of the textbox.

I do not have anything returned as expected or input displayed in the console if declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue(s)

There were a few issues with your code:

1. `var pokemonName = $('pokemon').val(pokemon);` you are setting the value of some element named `pokemon` (not valid) here
2. <s>`var data = JSON.parse(this.response);` where is *this.response* being set? Shouldn't we be receiving response in the callback?</s>
3. `request.send();` is inside of the onload event, so the request never gets sent

### Critiques

My main critique here is that you included a fairly large library (jQuery), and didn't utilize it to make the request. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  is well documented and cleans up a lot of the intricacies of XMLHttpRequest.

### The solution

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  var pokemonName = $('#pokemon').val();
  //event.preventDefault();
  getPokemonData(pokemonName);
})

function getPokemonData(pokemonName) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

  //GET request with link

  request.open('GET', 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + pokemonName, true);
  // request for data
  request.onload = function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response.currentTarget.response)
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status <= 400) {
      // outputs data
      console.log(data)
    } else {
      alert("Error");
    }
  }
  request.send();
}
```

```html
<input id="pokemon" value="12" />
<button>search</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Taking all the above issues into account, I was able to get a working example of what it should ultimately look like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: All valid & correct. `this.response`, will work though. `response` is part of `XMLHttpRequest`, and given the scope how this code's written, `this.response` would work.

Comment: I agree with everything you've said. While you were writing this, I built my own functional example, which turned out pretty much the same as yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nvau1g

Comment: @DaveSalomon ahh good catch, sometimes I feel like `XMLHttpRequest`, in particular, is sparsely documented just to mess with developers

Comment: This definitely helps @DerekPollard  I never notice that the response.send() was encapsulated incorrectly. I tried utilizing $.ajax ran into  similar issues.